# IIS equivalent on Mac

Tags: iphone, dashcode, osx-leopard

I am trying to develop a Dashcode application which uses the Mac as a local server. In windows IIS is used see and change the local server settings. 
What is the equivalent of IIS in Mac Osx?

Thank You All.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for Apache (turn it on in Sharing) but this is really a question for Superuser, not Stack Overflow the programming site...